# Is memory allocated each time I call PhotoImage

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a Tkinter GUI program that displays images(around 100 pics) based on the scale factor a user gives. Thereby I use PIL to resize the images, store them one after the other in an array as

```
My_Images = []
for i in range(100)
    img = Image.open("Pic"+ str(i) + ".gif")
    Zimg = img.resize((Z.Width,Z.Height))
    Zimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Zimg)
    My_Images.append(Zimage)
```

Z.Width and Z.Height is calculated by a function based on the user input of scale factor. Thereby the canvas that the GUI window uses is configured to display the Picture one after the other(referenced by the array) based on user navigation inputs.

What I am concerned about is when I print the array contents after multiple user based entries (of scaling factor), thereby doing multiple iterations for the above "for loop", the print command for the contents of the array My_Images gives "pyimage900", and similar such high numbers. I want to know if this has any negative effect on the memory allocation as after the nineth iteration of "for loop", "pyimage1"-"pyimage800" is of no use to me. 
Though the array is cleared every time before the "for loop" is initiated still the entries keep on increasing in the numerical suffix of "pyimage".

Does this memory allocation of the unused pyimage objects have any negative effects on memory? Do/Can i delete them, How?

Comment: the img = Image.open(...) line can be placed outside(before) the for loop.

Comment: For what purpose are the 'Zimage's being recorded in the My_Images array?

Comment: @VikhyatAgarwal Image.open(...) is for opening one image after the other, thereby its in the for loop.

Comment: @VikhyatAgarwal Zimage recorded in the My_Images array shall be used to display the respective resized image by accessing the array inex and configuring the canvas respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a variable like Zimage you can use the line:

```
del Zimage
```

If you want to delete an element from the My_Images array:

```
del My_Images[3]
```

Comment: No I'm not concerned about deleting the variable rather about what PhotoImage returns(pyimage1, pyimage2......) after successive iteration

Comment: Is there a way to alter the same pyimage-suffix rather than creating a succesively newer one